# Woocommerce cart amount AJAX shortcode

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, code-snippets

I've made a snippet to display the cart total in a shortcode. I use it at the checkout page (created a multistep checkout) before order validation.

```
add_shortcode( 'quote-total', 'get_quote_total' );
function get_quote_total(){
    $total        = WC()->cart->total;
    
    return '<div>'.wc_price($total).'</div>';
}

// USAGE: [quote-total]
```

Now, I would like to use AJAX to make the amount change when there is new data, like shipping.
Do you know how can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You should add some selector (e.g. class name) to your element:

```
return '<div class="step-cart-total">'.wc_price($total).'</div>';
```

Then you should be able to utilize `woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments` filter like so:

```
function custom_woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments( $fragments ) {

    // Ajaxify checkout step cart total
    ob_start();
    $total = WC()->cart->total;    
    echo '<div class="step-cart-total">'.wc_price($total).'</div>';    
    $fragments['.step-cart-total'] = ob_get_clean();

    return $fragments;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'custom_woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments');
```

Comment: Hi @Kristián, I've just follow your advice by adding a class name but price doesn't change when shipping or coupon code is done.